# How to get error code on image load error in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some legacy reason, I am loading an image via `jQuery` and on failure I need the error code(404 or 401) to show why did the load fail. How can I achieve it?

```
var img = $('#test')
    .load(function() {
        // Do something.
        console.log(img);
    })
    .error(function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {  
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(error);
    console.log(errorThrown);
       if(jqXHR.status && jqXHR.status==404)
       {
            alert("Something went wrong");
       }
    })
    .attr('src', "http://www.gravatar0.com/avatar/5e7856eb90f924b5cffb9fa75ca905ba?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG");
```

[JsBin](https://jsbin.com/bizobaf/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: `401` status code means the request is not authorized and it cannot access to the path.

Comment: Yes I get that, but I want this in the error callback so that I can handle

Comment: @Bhojendra How is it duplicate ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `Image` class:

```js
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function () {
  console.log('SUCCESS:');
  console.log(this);
};
image.onerror = function (e) {
  console.log('ERROR:');
  console.log(e);
};


image.src = 'http://www.gravatar0.com/avatar/5e7856eb90f924b5cffb9fa75ca905ba?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG';
```

Overriding `onload` function to check if the image is ready to use, and overriding `onerror` function to check if there is some error with the path.

Comment: Still don't get it - https://jsbin.com/gowusay/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 0):

The error and load methods are removed from version 3.0. So, I suggest you to use the jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on) method and bind the JavaScript events on them:

```
var img = $('#test')
    .on('load', function() {
      ...
    })
    .on('error', function(msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
      ...
    })
```

You can look into the docs for [onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) and [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: Nope still the same